# Partial molar volume of binary mixture

Tags: physical-chemistry, solutions, phase

A 2% (weight %) solution of a salt with Mr = 190.6 g mol-1 was prepared at 25 0C. The density of the prepared solution was 1.00926 g cm-3. The density of water at 25 0C is 0.99707 g cm-3, and the density of the crystalline salt was 3.00845 g cm-3.

a) ) What is the molar volume of the crystalline salt?

**molar volume of salt=(190.6g/mol)/(3.00845g/cm^3)= 63.4cm^3 /mol**

b) what's the partial molar volume of the salt at infinite dilution

**assuming the mass of solution =100g, w%:(mass of salt)/(mass of solution) x 100**

**w%:  (mass of salt)/100g*100= 2%**

**mass of salt= 2g**

**mass of water=100-2=98g**

**no.of mole salt= 2/190.6=0.010493mol**

**no.of mole of water=  98/18.02=5.4384mol**

**x_salt=  0.010493/(5.4384+0.010493) = 0.001925**

**x_water=1-0.001925=0.99881**

these are my workings for part a and b. My understanding of part b is to find partial molar volume via dV/dn, but I can't seem to find the difference in volumes, let alone infinite dilutions...I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. Do I have any misconceptions?

-struggling physical chem student

Comment: Please, always use as the first step a general algebraic solution, for 4 reasons.: 1/better grasp of principles for OP  2/ better orientation and spotting eventual mistakes 3/solution reusability and permanent value 
4/ The site focus is on helping understanding principles and solution procedures, not on solving particular tasks. Use eventually [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88) for mathematical/chemical expression/formula formatting.

Comment: Hint: What would be the solution volume without the salt ?

Comment: I see. Sorry about that